# Is it possible to use the solution vector returned at every solver time step by solve_ivp during the simulation time?

Tags: python, scipy

I have been trying hard to find a way to access my solution vector returned at every solver successful time step for other calculations during the run.
Simplifying my problem as :
For time span `[0,.001]`
I solve a differential equation `Xdot =A*X+B*U` (State-space equation)
using

```
sol=solve_ivp(conv,tspan,X0)
```

At every `sol.t` point, a solution for `X` is computed. I want access to that solution during the run. 
`sol.y` returns the whole array at the end of the simulation but I  want the solution for `X` at every time point so that it get used in the function `conv` during the run.

Comment: Use the t_eval argument, then you will intermediate solutions returned at every time in t_eval

Comment: t_eval also gives the solution after the equations have been solved and not during the run

Comment: What do you mean by "during the run"? The solutions t_eval returns are the intermediate solutions which the solver computes during the integration process. Are you wanting some sort of callback or something so that you can do other calculations?

Comment: Yes exactly , A callback to do other calculations . During the run means, during the time span only when the solver is still solving the differential equation

Comment: The current integration routines don't expose any sort of callback mechanismI am aware of. There are user definable "events" which can be evaluated during solution, but those are also not reported until the integration is completed

Comment: Is there any way to create a callback manually?

Comment: The only way I can think of is by writing your time stepping system built over other scipy methods, which it sounds like you should have done in the first place given your use case

Comment: Are you talking about fixed step solvers like Euler?

Comment: No, I am talking about using the existing solvers (I guess you are using RK45 here by accident or design), and using them in your own time stepping loop which includes whatever other callback actions you require

Comment: Time stepping loop as in? Is it where the step size is adjusted by us? Can you share any useful link on this?

Comment: Just break the integration interval into a series of smaller steps (like t_eval), use the integration method of your choice to integrate between the sub-intervals, perform your call back actions, and repeat until you have integrated the whole time interval

Answer (score 0):

Inside the derivative function you have access to y.  Each time solve_ivp accesses it you can store y in data arrays that are passed to the function using "args=".  You can also write to disk or update a plot, etc.

Answer (score -1):

How about wrapping your function `conv`?

```
def fun(t,y):
    print(t)
    return conv(t,y)
```

It will print the value of `t` everytime the function is called.

Comment: The function will be called many times by the solver with values which are not an instantaneous solution of the ODE system. There is no way to tell what would be a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but would it be possible to fetch the last solution before a new timestep? So save the current result, and if the timestep changes, return the last result?

Comment: The ODE function isn't supplied with a timestep, and the ODE solver can call it for all sorts of reasons, like Jacobian matrix construction (in the case of implicit methods), or optimal timestep calculations (in the case of explicit methods), so I don't see how that could work